# Is it possible to create a regular language from an non regular language?

Tags: languages, regular-expressions, automata

I am wondering if it is possible to create a regular language from a irregular language if we add or remove finite number of words from it?

say L is irregular, can we add or remove finite number of words to create a regular language?

i might be mistaken, but since all regular languages are finite - if we add a finite amount to a non regular language - it still stays non regular, but if we substract, let's say a finite amount from infinity, it is still infinity.

so is it safe to say that in both cases a regular language cannot not be obtained by adding/substracting a finite amount of words?

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [cs.se], but consider expressing your question more formally first. E.g. you want to “add or remove a finite number of elements” – what is an element here? A word w in the language L? And what precisely do you mean by a non-regular language? Something like context free or recursively enumerable languages (i.e. the enclosing sets of languages in the Chomsky hierarchy)?

Comment: Note that looking at this problem in reverse might be simpler: can adding a finite number of words w1, w2, … wn to a regular language L make that language non-regular? No, the resulting language is still regular. The language could e.g. be described with the regular expression `w1|w2|...|wn|R` where R is a regular expression describing the original language L. The question whether *removing* a number of words from a regular language keeps the language regular is more difficult, but I think it could be proven by using an NFA.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment - i am in the beginning of the course and we have not yet encountered chomsky hierarchy. by element i meant words, and i will correct that in an edit

Comment: i didn't understand the second comment quite well. the question is about adding/substracting a finite amount of words from a non regular  language, i.e if we add/substract a finite amount of words from a nonr regular language - can make it regular? and i think that the answer is no

Comment: @mathnoobie Parrying on what @amon stated, I also want to point out that `regular` really needs to be contextualized. From a statistics point of view, I read `regular` as denoting the concatenation of a sequence of phenomena, in which all phenomena are identical. For example, heating water to 100 C, all things being equal, is `a regular phenomenon` that results in boiling water. Any deviation from that, say you heat up the water to 200 and it still does not boil, would be a literal miracle. Non-regular would be `frequent` phenomena, such as what you usually have for dinner; it varies.

Comment: thank you for your comment akiva, but this is the term that is regularily being used in automata theory: regular and non regular languages. even why i searched in google and similar sites before asking the question, all were using the same terminology

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finite Languages are trivially enumerable just by listing their members, and thus weaker than even the regular languages. Therefore the entire hierarchy of formal languages deals only with infinite languages, and every higher-up language is infinite in a *qualitatively new* way. For instance, regular languages can't count things, but context-free languages can.

*None* of these differences can be bridged by adding a finite number of elements, so yes, neither adding nor removing them can move between regular and non-regular.